# zooming in scrollview ios6

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, ios6, autoresizingmask

I am trying to implement a simple ImageView in a scrollview to display an image. I want to particularly implement the pinch to zoom feature. I implemented the following code (which is taken from one of the Objective C sample codes on the apple websites). I tested the zooming thoroughly on ios 5 and there seems to be no problem. However when I ported my code to ios 6 and I test my zoom feature, after a while I get the following error message and my app crashes with skewed zoom results.

Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)

NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x8808360 h=--- v=--- V:[UIWindow:0x744db00(480)],
NSLayoutConstraint:0x71286d0 UIView:0x71222c0.bottom == UIWindow:0x744db00.bottom,
NSLayoutConstraint:0x7128650 V:|-(20)-[UIView:0x71222c0]   (Names: '|':UIWindow:0x744db00 ),
NSLayoutConstraint:0x7120c50 UIImageView:0x7451630.bottom == UIScrollView:0x71206f0.bottom,
NSLayoutConstraint:0x7120c90 V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7451630]   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0x71206f0 ),
NSLayoutConstraint:0x7120bd0 UIImageView:0x7451630.centerY == UIScrollView:0x71206f0.centerY,
NSLayoutConstraint:0x7122a50 V:|-(10)-[UIScrollView:0x71206f0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x71222c0 ),
NSLayoutConstraint:0x7122940 V:[UIScrollView:0x71206f0]-(38)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x71222c0 )

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.

I tried doing a google search for this problem but I am not getting good results. The code I am using is as follows. Help is greatly Appreciated

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // set the tag for the image view
    [self.imageView setTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];

    // calculate minimum scale to perfectly fit image width, and begin at that scale
    NSLog(@"[imageScrollView frame].size.width : %f",[self.scrollVIew frame].size.width);
    NSLog(@"[imageView frame].size.width : %f",[self.imageView frame].size.width);

    NSLog(@"[imageScrollView frame].size.height : %f",[self.scrollVIew frame].size.height);
    NSLog(@"[imageView frame].size.height : %f",[self.imageView frame].size.height);

    float minimumScale = [self.scrollVIew frame].size.width  / [self.imageView frame].size.width;
    minimumScale = 300.0/1200.0;

    NSLog(@"minimumScale : %f",minimumScale);

    [self.scrollVIew setMinimumZoomScale:minimumScale];
    [self.scrollVIew setZoomScale:minimumScale];

    NSLog(@"imageScrollView.zoomScale : %f",self.scrollVIew.zoomScale);
    NSLog(@"imageScrollView.minimumZoomScale = minimumScale : %f",self.scrollVIew.minimumZoomScale = minimumScale);

    self.scrollVIew.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1200.0, 800.0);
    self.scrollVIew.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return [self.scrollVIew viewWithTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];
}
```

Vivek

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your `UIImageView` Programatically, and add in a subview of your `UIScrollView`. But you must make this inside of the viewDidAppear.

Just your UIScrollView can be made in StoryBoard!

And you will set the `scrollView.contentSize` inside of "`viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`" and not inside of the viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

Disable auto layout in your XIB file.  It will be under the left most tab in the properties section on the right.  You are probably using it without knowing it.  If you are using it intentionally, then try to sort out your constraints so they don't conflict with each other.

Comment: Thanks borrden. I am able to get it working when i uncheck the auto layout. However if I want the auto layout to remain as you said I need to sort out the constants. But I am wondering as to how to go about that. For instance when I create the view and the components, the system automatically sets the constraints fr me. In this case how to sort the views? Also I am not able to disable the auto layout for a particular vc. All the vc s in the navigation controller are getting their auto layout property disabled

Comment: Giving an auto layout tutorial will be far too long for here.  Google has some . Also notice this line in your error message -> Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints